# Google ML job being terminated randomly and restarted without reason given

Tags: keras, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I have a Gcloud ML Engine training job that usually works great on ML Engine however recently I've noticed that the VM seems to be restarting randomly. This causes it to lose all progress (my code doesn't do anything clever like reload the cached checkpoints) so adds to the cost of this operation and makes it take longer. The only messages given in the gcloud logs are:

> Terminated by service. If the job is supposed to continue running, it
>   will be restarted on other VM shortly.
>
> Module completed; cleaning up.
>
> Clean up finished.
>
> [service] Internal error occurred for the current attempt.

It's not clear to me whether the "Internal error" is referring to the problem that caused the VM to go down or to the clean up attempt.

This has happened on multiple occasions now. I am running two jobs simultaneously so perhaps it is a resource problem? Is there anything I can do to make this happen less often?

I am training with Keras.

The GPU config file is as follows:

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: standard_gpu
  runtimeVersion: "1.13"
```

Comment: Can you send your job ids to cloudml-feedback@google.com please?

Comment: @GuoqingXu Ok I have done so, sorry for the delay.

Comment: I got the same error on my job this morning. @Patrick do let us know the reason for this error if it comes to your knowledge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching one of the jobs to be on a different region stopped this occurring for me which will do for now. Will mark this as the answer if this proves to be consistent unless a real explanation materializes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has nothing to do with how many jobs you are running at the same time. The log Terminated by service. If the job is supposed to continue running, it will be restarted on other VM shortly. means that the VM running your job got interrupted by Google Compute Engine maintenance event for software or hardware updates.  In case of those events, the ML Engine will retry your job in another VM automatically. 
It seems like you cancelled the job and thus that retry never happened.
Should you encounter a similar issue again, please do not cancel the job but check back later.
Please let us know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is not right, I did indeed cancel one of the jobs manually but that was well after it had already been restarted by the service.